# How to solve quotes issue when inserting html into database?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

Due to the quotes that lot of html elements use it's quite difficult to insert it into the database. What do you guys suggest? Some element use single/multiple quotes. I am using PostgreSQL but i think this is the same on different dbms

Example of an statement:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME VALUES ('faf98cef-4589-4d9b-a60e-ac4490bc4c63', 'c4cb1381-f24c-11e9-b8e2-f742f4b6cc52', '{# include '$path/aro.ftl' #} <!-- module begin --> <table efw-data="module" class="full-width max-width-default" align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: auto; margin: 0 auto; "> <tbody> <tr> <td style="">......
```

My last option is to encode / decode the html but i would like to save it like it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally in SQL, a single quote is escaped by doubling it: `'Arthur''s House'`

But for a long string, it's easier to use use Postgres' [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING), then you don't need to change anything in your input string.

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (col1, col2, html_col)
VALUES (
  'faf98cef-4589-4d9b-a60e-ac4490bc4c63', 
  'c4cb1381-f24c-11e9-b8e2-f742f4b6cc52', 
   $html${# include '$path/aro.ftl' #} ....... $html$
);
```

---

If you are doing this from within a programming language, you should not concatenate values like that into a SQL query to begin with.

It is **much** better to use a "prepared statement" where you have a placeholder for each value. How exactly you do that depends on the programming language you are using.

Comment: I was looking for an answer that wouldn't require changes and this is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you inserting manually? If yes, just add two times the quotes that don't delimit the column data.

If you are adding via software, try to see if your language have the prepared statements.

As example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME VALUES ('faf98cef-4589-4d9b-a60e-ac4490bc4c63', 'c4cb1381-f24c-11e9-b8e2-f742f4b6cc52', '{# include ''$path/aro.ftl'' #} <!-- module begin --> <table efw-data="module" class="full-width max-width-default" align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: auto; margin: 0 auto; "> <tbody> <tr> <td style="">...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double and single quotes. Single quotes for inside the html code and double quotes for outside.E.g `"<button class='btn1'>Click me</button>"`

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME VALUES ('faf98cef-4589-4d9b-a60e-ac4490bc4c63', 'c4cb1381-f24c-11e9-b8e2-f742f4b6cc52', "{# include '$path/aro.ftl' #} <!-- module begin --> <table efw-data='module' class='full-width max-width-default' align='center' width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='table-layout: auto; margin: 0 auto;'> <tbody> <tr> <td style=''>");
```